# Removed for security Reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have a question about my Puzzling Stack Exchange post: [Trojan Horse Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51569/trojan-horse-puzzle)

So I posted a puzzle, called the Trojan Horse, where text was hidden inside of the image (the puzzle), I even tagged it `steganography`. Why was it deleted for security reasons? I named it Trojan Horse, since the text is hidden inside of the image, and people think the image is the puzzle, but it's really hiding the true puzzle.

**Edit #1:** I put a link to the image instead of using imgur, but I had reasons for doing that:

> Imgur says Your image is too large to upload.
>   Also, image hosters might mess up the puzzle by modifying the image *(removing steganography)*,
>   so I self hosted it to ensure it remains solvable.

Italics = added info (the puzzle's already ruined so I might as well give it away)

Comment: Next time use a smaller resolution.

Answer (score 5):

It was deleted because it linked to an offsite resource and required that users download it and open it. (It was an image, where "opening" was looking at text hidden inside the image, but the concerns are still very applicable.)

This poses a *massive* security risk for a number of reasons:

- Asking us to open a file without knowing what it is.
- The file being hosted on a "sketchy" website (not something that scans its files for viruses like, say, Google Drive)
- setting a precedent for opening these files in the future, *even if nothing is wrong with this one*

Previous posts on meta show that [similar puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4555/should-we-disallow-capture-the-flag-puzzles-where-the-user-has-to-install-soft/4556#4556) are disallowed. Due to the similarity and security risk, I went ahead and deleted it.

---

(Also, even if I *hadn't* deleted it, it would most likely be closed. Puzzles that rely on offsite resources that have a high risk of becoming inaccessible are considered off-topic, since the puzzle can easily become unsolvable.)

Comment: Then, how would I put steganography in my puzzle? Imgur would probably remove that stuff.

Comment: @NoahCristino [Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49341/where-is-steven-the-stegosaurus) is one example. There are many similar examples. There are many other methods like [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50733/the-legend-of-sally-the-cow)

Comment: As a general note (no comment on this question in particular), it's usually a good idea to **explain mod actions as fully as possible**. Instead of just "Deleting for security reasons", you could have written something a bit more detailed, including maybe the bullet points and link from this answer, so that the OP could more easily understand the deletion without having to ask about it on meta. (Of course, sometimes there are things you *can't* explain publicly, but that comes under "as fully *as possible*".)