# Are puzzles with large audio files allowed?

Tags: discussion

I was planning on making a puzzle where an audio file (maybe 5-10 minutes or more) must be analyzed to solve the puzzle. Would something like this be allowed, and if so, how could I share the file? I thought of the following methods:

- upload to an audio hosting site (compression may ruin the audio?)
- base64 the audio data and upload it to pastebin (with instructions to decode)
- base64 the audio data and put it in the question (may make the question way too long/spammy?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Audio/Sound/Video-Puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6505/audio-sound-video-puzzles)

Comment: You can always create an i.stack.imgur image where every pixel's rgb values represent 3 characters.

Comment: @bobble the answers don't seem to mention audio, and I also provided a way which makes the puzzle self-contained, so I think this is different

Comment: @LukasRotter are images stored loselessly?

Comment: @FireCubez As long as it's a PNG under 1MB, yes.

Comment: @LukasRotter oh okay, great to know, I'll do that then!

Comment: The image should serve as a "back-up" to make sure the puzzle stays self-contained. As long as the image is included, you can of course also put a base64 pastebin or similar for easier access.