# Is using external servers in puzzles allowed?

Tags: discussion

Can we use external servers as part of our puzzles? As in:

- Pastebin
- YouTube
- Mediafire
- A custom hosted server (which will eventually go down, I don't have infinite money sadly. Although I hope the information in the server will be posted in an answer before it goes down)
- etc...

Comment: Probably a combo duplicate of [Is using a personal website to host content for a puzzle frowned upon?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/is-using-a-personal-website-to-host-content-for-a-puzzle-frowned-upon) and [Internet-wide puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6299/5373)

Comment: @Randal'Thor yeah, thanks