# Can you have riddles that require information from a certain site?

Tags: discussion

I was thinking about making a riddle that needed a certain site. For example, [What3Words](http://what3words.com) is a site that translates 3 words into a 3 by 3 meter square on a map. However, the only way you could solve a puzzle that used 3 words is if you had the site. Is it ok to create puzzles that require you to use a certain website? What if you add clues to hint to that site?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think this question is better than the other. My inclination would be to keep this and close the other as a dupe. The other question asked about personal web sites which is obviously out. We have a recognized external site for images which is obviously in. On other se sites it is ok to link to microsoft or imdb. In this case I would lean towards "no" as an answer but this, I feel, is more of a grey area than the other question.

Comment: See also some of the reasoning and resources mentioned [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6070).

Answer (score 1):

We try to keep our puzzles 100% self-contained on this site as it is impossible to know how long other sites will stay up.

My vote on this would be no.